# Add line from a textfile to a textbox in php

Tags: php, html

I want to add a specific text from a specific line into a textbox in my html code.

I get the line from a textfile (which is a BASH script) by using:

```
<?php 
    $myFile = "C:\dat300backups\script.txt";
        $lines = file($myFile);//file in to an array
        echo $lines[13];
?>
```

Then I want the text I get from:

```
echo $lines[13];
```

to be inserted into a texbox in:

```
IP Subnet: <input type="text" name="ipsubnet" value="I want the line here"><br>
```

Here is the whole code:

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Rate Limiter</title>
    </head>

    <body>

    <?php 

    $myFile = "C:\dat300backups\script.txt";
    $lines = file($myFile);//file in to an array
    echo $lines[13];
    echo("<br>");
    echo $lines[14];
    echo("<br>");
    echo $lines[15];
    echo("<br>");   
    echo $lines[16];
    echo("<br>");
    echo $lines[17];
    echo("<br>");
    echo $lines[18];
    echo("<br>");
    echo $lines[19];
    echo("<br>");
    echo $lines[20];
    echo("<br>");
    echo $lines[21];
    echo("<br>");
    echo("<br>");



    ?>

    <form>
    IP Subnet: <input type="text" name="ipsubnet" value=""><br>
    IP From: <input type="text" name="ipfrom"><br>
    IP To: <input type="text" name="ipto"><br>
    WAN: <input type="text" name="wan"><br>
    LAN: <input type="text" name="lan"><br>
    Traffic Control Path: <input type="text" name="tcpath"><br>
    PacketLimit: <input type="text" name="packetlimit"><br>
    Download Rate: <input type="text" name="drate"> kbit/s<br>
    Upload Rate: <input type="text" name="urate"> kbit/s<br>
    </form>

    <form name="input" action="html_form_action.asp" method="get">
    Password: <input type="password" name="pwd">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>





    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a PHP variable as a value into your html code in the below way. Don't forget to save your file as .php extension and also the below code should be in html format.

Here you are for the short tag (not a good practice) :

```
IP Subnet: <input type="text" name="ipsubnet" value="<?=$lines[13]; ?>">
```

Here you are for the 'classic' tag :

```
IP Subnet: <input type="text" name="ipsubnet" value="<?php echo $lines[13]; ?>">
```

Comment: You might want to explain a little, because this answer is useless for someone who's learning.

Comment: Never give examples with short tags in it. I can drive a beginner crazy when it works locally but when he publish it on the server it don't. Short tags need to be enabled in the PHP configuration.

Comment: Don't bully me for that.. 

He's beginner, but if he don't make some burning ass mistakes (short tag, perfect for that), he will not learn quickly.

You need to make mistake (spend 2 days on a missing semicolon ? Check !) to learn effectively.

Thank's for the constructive argument, thought.

Answer (score 0):

```
IP Subnet: <input type="text" name="ipsubnet" value="<?php echo $lines[13]; ?>">
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to clean up your code a little:

```
<?php 

    $myFile = "C:\dat300backups\script.txt";
    $lines = file($myFile);//file in to an array
    for ($i = 13, $i <= 21; $i++) {
        echo "<input type=\"text\" name=\"ipsubnet\" value=\"" . $lines[$i] . "\"><br>\n";
    }

    echo("<br>");



?>
```